# Temporarily holding items in a ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-loadermanager

I am looking for a solution to temporarily house data in a ListView without saving to SQL until a parent table has been saved. The reason being, this data is dependent on a parent SQL Table via Foreign Keys. The UI displays the Parent Table and 2 of it's children tables.

To better illustrate this, let's say we had a parent SQL table called **Dog** linked to two linked tables called **Toy** and **Collar**.

The UI for this example allows you to enter **Dog.name** and gives you an interface to add **Toys.name** and **Collars.name** in the same Activity.

When I click a button which adds **Toy.name**, I can insert to SQL, but I do not have a parent **Dog._id** to link to, since I have not saved the **Dog** record. The added **Toy.name** still needs to be retained in the ListView, but can't yet be linked via Foreign Key

Some will be thinking *Why not seperate the tables into 3 sequential Activities to avoid this altogether?*. I am trying to reduce the amount of screens, want it all in one Activity for usability reasons. But perhaps the knowledge base out there knows an efficient way to go about this.

So my question is, **what is the best way to go about this?**
Should I insert into SQL, then update the Foreign Key later?
Should I use an ArrayAdapter for the ListViews in insert mode, and switch to Cursor LoaderManager for update/delete mode?

Comment: When you insert the Toy for the Dog, is the Dog in question already added? Do you add the Dog before giving the user opportunity to insert Toy?

Comment: The Dog is not already added, because the EditText containing Dog.Name is on the same screen for the Toy ListView

Comment: I think it's better to add the Dog to the DB as soon as you start creating the Toy. Unless you can have a Toy with no Dog that's the better way to do it.

Comment: Right, that would be the logical way of doing it. But in this case, I am trying to put User Experience before practicality. I want the user to be able to put in Dog.Name, Collars, and Toys all in the same screen

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Then when the user touches save or whatever, just add everything to your database starting with the dog. Then you can get the id of the dog by doing this `SELECT ROWID from SQL_LITE_SEQUENCE order by ROWID DESC limit 1` and then add everything else.